# 습기찬 and 지폐는 grammar and meaning difference

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

습기찬 눅눅한 지폐는 걸릴 수 있으니 사용하지 말아주세요.

I have some questions relating the sentence above. Hope someone could shed some light on it.

1. I think 습기찬 and 눅눅한 are formed from verbs or adjectives 습기차다 and 눅눅하다 by adding -ㄴ/은, -는 adnominal suffixes here. However, some of my friends think that 습기찬 is a noun and it is not formed by adding that suffix. She also thinks that it is not allowed to have two words with -ㄴ/은, -는 adnominal suffixes close each other and all modify the noun 지폐 like that. I would like to hear your opinion on this?
2. What is the difference in meaning between 습기찬 and 눅눅한?

Thanks.

Comment: 습기찬 and 지폐는 -> 습기찬 and 눅눅한, 지폐 -> 눅눅, right?

Comment: Can you share whrre you see this sentence? And is your friend native? I think she is but her second point is wrong.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: it is put on a vending machine. My friend is not a native also.

Comment: Well, there's no single word `습기차다`. _They_ are `습기` and `차다`, so you _have to_ space between them: `습기(가) 차다`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 습기차다 is not an adjective, but a verb.  It is a contraction of 습기(가) 차다: "차다" here is the verb "to be filled" (e.g., 병에 물이 가득 **찼다**), but it is also commonly used with 물기 or 습기 to mean "get wet (or get covered with dew) because of high humidity".

Random examples from the web:

> 비올 때 차안에 **습기가 차는** 이유가 뭐죠? (Why do we get dew inside the car when it rains?)
>
> 창문 주변이나 벽 모서리, 장판 밑, 욕실의 타일 등은 **습기가 쉽게 차는** 곰팡이 상습발생 지역이다.

눅눅하다 is an adjective that means "full of moisture; become soft/flaccid with moisture", usually in an unpleasant way.  So, in the example sentence "습기찬" and "눅눅한" have a very similar meaning.

If you ask me, I would use only one of 습기찬 or 눅눅한, or if I really wanted to be pedantic, I could say "**습기가 차거나 눅눅한** 지폐는 걸릴 수 있으니 사용하지 말아 주세요."

However, just saying "습기찬 눅눅한 지폐", with two consecutive -ㄴ, is not grammatically incorrect: it is just a poor style here, IMHO (especially since they are more or less redundant).